# phone not coming out of recovery mode

Tags: recovery-mode

Yesterday an update came to my mobile. I updated and was installing the update an then an error occured. After that i restarted my mobile and from then on a no command screen is coming. My mobile is not rooted. Also in the downside it is showing No .zip file in internal storage. Please help asap.

Answer (score 0):

Samsung Galaxy S4
Step 1
Power off the device, then remove the battery to make sure the phone is completely powered off. Reinsert the battery.

Step 2
Press and hold the “Home” button, “Power” key and “Volume Up” key simultaneously until the phone vibrates.
Step 3
Release the “Power” button when you feel the vibration, but continue to hold the “Home” and “Volume Up” keys. The Android Recovery screen displays. Release the “Volume Up” and “Home” buttons.

Step 4
Press the “Volume Down” key to scroll to the Wipe Data/Factory Reset option, then press the “Power” button to select the option.

Step 5
Press “Volume Down” to highlight the “Delete All User Data” option, then press “Power” to select. The device resets, then the screen displays the “Reboot System Now” option.

Step 6
Press the “Power” button to reboot the device into normal mode.

HTC EVO 4G LTE
Step 1
Power off the device, then remove the battery to make sure the phone is completely powered down. Reinsert the battery.

Step 2
Press and hold the “Volume Down” key, then press and hold the “Power” button. The device powers up to the Android Recovery screen.

Step 3
Release both keys when the Android Recovery images appear.

Step 4
Press “Volume Down” to scroll to the “Factory Reset” option. Press the “Power” key to select. The device is reset to factory settings, then boots back up into normal mode.
          Hope this will help you